# Regex for time using positive lookahead with g-mail integration

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following data coming in that I am trying to capture using a regex. I can't seem to get it to work I want to use the white space as a stop but so far no luck.

```
located on 10/6/2015 5:18:14 GMT
```

regex that I'm using:

```
2015\s*(.+?)(?=\sGMT)
```

I'm trying to simply get the `5:18:14` but I end up capturing `5 5:18:14`

Any help would be great, I'm sure it's a simple fix but I just can't think of it right now.

---

Thank you everyone for the help, I ended up with this as my final script. I ended up using shaA.T's regex.

I am getting the data that I need from the gmail emails however it only seems to run on the first message of each thread. I've been playing around with different methods from google but no luck.

I'm trying to make this script go through every single message in the g-mail inbox not just the first message of each thread. You guys have any knowledge with the g-mail app? This is my first time working with google scripts.

```
function processInboxToSheet() {
  //var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  // Have to get data separate to avoid google app script limit!



 var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread();
 for (var i = 0 ; i < messages.length; i++) {

var content = messages[0].getRawContent();

   var SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets";
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';  

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);  




    var content = messages[0].getRawContent();

    // implement your own parsing rule inside
    if (content) {
      var tmp;
      tmp = content.match(/\<\!\-\-\soutRadius\s\s\[*(.+?)\]/);

      var radius = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Unknown Radius';

      tmp = content.match(/\<\!\-\-\sX\s\s\[*(.+?)\]/);
      var longitude = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Unknown Latitude';

      tmp = content.match(/\<\!\-\-\sY\s\s\[*(.+?)\]/);
      var latitude = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Unknown Longitude';

      tmp = content.match(/\The mobile number was located on\s*(.+?)\s/);
      var date = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'Unknown date';

      tmp = content.match(/([\d:]*)\s*GMT/);
      var time = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'Unknown time';

      sheet.appendRow([date, time, longitude, latitude, radius]);

      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }


};
```

Comment: Please post your actual code. Regexes don't exist in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
/([\d:]*)\s*GMT/
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/tM2lU1/1)

Answer (score 0):

This works, plus works only for time values - meaning it would not match *foo GMT*:

```
[0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2}(?=\sGMT)
```

Explanation:

```
[0-9]{1,2}        One or two numbers (the hour)
(:[0-9]{1,2}){2}  Two times a colon followed by two numbers (minutes, seconds)
(?=\sGMT)         The lookahead
```

https://regex101.com/r/zR9iE8/2